# How to create page layout in sharepoint 2010 wss? please help

Tags: layout, sharepoint-2010

How to create page layout in sharepoint 2010 wss? please help

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean WSS, you cannot create page layouts as this is a part of the Publishing feature available only in MOSS